# RactJs : TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'json' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

**This is my sample code:**

```
const updatedNav = ({ json }) => {
  console.log(json); // throwing undefined
  const title = json.title;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

updatedNav.getInitialProps = async (router) => {
  const pid = "3456789";
  const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  });

  const response = await fetch(`${config.apiHost}api/abc?pid=${pid}`, {
    agent
  });
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log('checkjson',json); // it is not even getting called
  return {
    json: json
  };
};
export default updatedNav;
```

**Result:**
the console.log is throwing "undefined" and the error message is pointing to this line "export const updatedNav = ({ json }) => {"

*Server Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'json' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.*

Can someone please help resolve this issue or find out what causes it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting the data in `console.log`?

Comment: no it is undefined. The error is pointing to this line export const updatedNav = ({ json }) => {

Comment: Can you check if you are getting this data?
`  const json = await response.json();`

Comment: I added the console.log under the const json but this console log is not getting picked up
const json = await response.json();
  console.log('datajson',json);

Comment: What about the const response=..?

Comment: same thing the console is not getting called for the response as well console.log('response data',response);

Comment: Data fetching methods like `getInitialProps` can only be used in page components, they do not work in regular components.